# Wiring a ceiling fan with a remote and 2 wall switches

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I recently purchased a [Hunter Avia Low Profile](https://www.costco.com/hunter-avia-low-profile-led-48%22-ceiling-fan.product.100424794.html) ceiling fan that came with a remote that I'd like to control using the 2 switches on the wall plus the remote control. Ideally, I'd like to control the light from one switch and the fan from the other while controlling the fan speed from the remote.

**From ceiling:** Black, Blue, and White.
**From remote receiver (right side):**  Black and White
**From remote receiver (left side):** Blue and Yellow
**From fan:** Black, Blue, and White

Is this wiring correct for what I want to achieve?

1. Ceiling-Black to Receiver-Black
2. Ceiling-White to Receiver-White to Fan-White
3. Ceiling-Red to Fan-Blue
4. Receiver-Yellow to Fan-Black
5. Cap Receiver-Blue

[image]

Comment: so the light will not be controled by remote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wiring looks good. The only thing is that when you turn off the fan from the switch, the receiver will probably forget what speed the fan was set to, as it is probably designed for constant power. When you turn the fan back on, the receiver may default to off and you will then need to use the remote too to turn on the fan and set the speed.

My recommendation is to forget the wall fan switch and just use the remote for the fan. (The wall light switch is fine.) You can leave the fan switch wired and just leave it on.

If you don't like this, you'll need a different fin.

Comment: The wall light switch may be a Code requirement.  When a guest or first responder enters a room for the first time, they will reach where light switches are to be found, and operate if necessary every switch. *A light MUST come on when they do*.  Exception made for switched receptacles, because it is presumed the citizen will plug a floor lamp into that.